# Compare Part of String 1 with the Second string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two string columns like below

```
Column01               Column02

ABC School System      Worked in Private school.
```

i want to match these columns such that if any single word from columns A is available in the column B it gives a match result. In this case the word "School" is present in both the columns so this should be considered as a match.

A single word from Column A can be defined as any string of letters with length of more than 3 and having spaces at the both sides or having space at either of one side and nothing on the other side (to cater the starting and closing word).

How can i do this in SQL Server?

Comment: what have you tried so far? why are sql server 2008 and sql server 2012 both tagged?

Comment: I know of the basic string command of "like" but that's not helpful in this case.

Comment: I have both the versions , Server 2008 and 2012. So either of those will work for me.

Comment: based on your definition one word would be `School` and the other `school.` notice `.` at the end of the second word. these will not match

Comment: @ughai, You are definitely right here, but i guess you got the what's the requirement. Let's say "ABC School System." should be giving a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an `XML` by using space as a token and then using `.nodes()` to get the words from the `xml` column and compare them together. Something like this

```
WITH Table1 as 
(
    SELECT 1 as ID,'ABC School System' as col1, 'Worked in Private school'  as col2 
), CTE2 as 
(
    SELECT M.id,c.value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(100)') COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS as col1val,c2.value('text()[1]','VARCHAR(100)') COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  as col2val
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id,
        CONVERT(XML,'<i>' + REPLACE(col1,' ','</i><i>') + '</i>') col1,
        CONVERT(XML,'<i>' + REPLACE(col2,' ','</i><i>') + '</i>') col2
        FROM Table1
    )M
    CROSS APPLY col1.nodes('i') as t(c)
    CROSS APPLY col2.nodes('i') as t2(c2)
)
SELECT ID,col1val,col2val
FROM CTE2
WHERE col1val = col2val
    AND LEN(col1val) > 3
    AND LEN(col2val) > 3
```

Comment: This really works. I will try to incorporate into the SQL Query. Thanks once again.